# undefined references using \usepgfplotslibrary{external}

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I use MikTex 2.9 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I do not have and will not have Admin rights on this machine.

I have a lot of tikzpictures and curves in my article so I use tikz with

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
```

and this works generally fine. But in some figures I refer to equations or acronyms. For these, I get the error:

```
latex warning reference 'eq:someeq' in external pictures 'blabla' could not been resolved on input line...
```

and the same for the acronyms...

Is there a solution other than editing it manually (its only in 4 figures...but bothers me)

EDIT: yes I tried what the compiler suggested:

```
-shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "xxx-figure25" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob {xxx}\input {xxx}"
```

This does not work - still question marks in the figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple: just put `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` around the figure enviroment.

```
\tikzexternaldisable 
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   %figure with some reference
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{a caption}
 \label{fig:somefigure}
\end{figure}
\tikzexternalenable
```